# What are the names of each window on a typical non-commercial vehicle?

Tags: window

Please list the windows on a vehicle starting from the front, i.e. the windshield.

The three "typical" vehicles I'm thinking of are car/SUV, van, and truck.

I'm looking for things like:

- The little triangle pieces that are sometimes in front of the front windows
- The triangle pieces after the rear windows
- The differentiation between the first set of back windows on a van and the second set
- The small rectangle of glass on an extended cab truck
- All the other obscure windows I'm  forgetting about

Pictures might be helpful, but are not required.

Comment: This might work better if _you_ provided a picture and gave letters or numbers to all the items you want the names of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Windshield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windshield)** - mandatory (windscreen in the U.K.)

**[Vent Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter_glass)** - optional, hinge outward from the front doors

**Front Windows** - mandatory windows in the front (or only) doors

**[Sunroof / Moonroof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunroof)** - optional, in roof. Can be [panoramic](http://www.motortrend.com/features/mt_hot_list/1504_vehicles_offering_panoramic_sunroofs_for_less_than_50000/viewall.html).

**Rear Windows** - optional, in rear doors (if applicable)

**[Rear Sunroof / Moonroof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunroof)** - optional, secondary window in roof (found in some Tesla Model S, MINI Cooper, etc.)

**[Quarter Glass / Valence Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter_glass)** - optional, stationary or vented windows in doors or behind the doors, on the sides.

**[Opera Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_window)** - rare in modern vehicles, optional stationary porthole windows behind the rear doors, on the sides. Typically found in 1970s luxury vehicles.

**Hatch Glass / Rear Window / Rear Windshield / Back Windshield** - optional, rear facing window.

Answer (score 1):

ICV Windows are Individually Controlled Ventilation windows. They are the little triangle-shaped windows that were in front of the front windows on older cars.  [image]